# Wrap divs according to the bootstrap row conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have following condition in which what i want is when my child div's first class `col-md-4` and beneath div class's  numeric digits 4+4+4 >= 12 then wrap those in div having class row.Fidle of my problem [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdC4Q/3/)

```
<div class="row questionsRows">
    <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
     <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
</div>
```

now i want to wrap divs in a row when my count of inner div's class is 12.
like this

```
<div class="row questionsRows">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Code i have tried :

```
function WrapRows() {

    var RowComplete = 0;
    var divs;
    $('.questionsRows').children('.coulmnQuestions').each(function () {
        debugger;
        var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
        var getFirstClass = classes[0];
        var value = getFirstClass.slice(7);

        RowComplete = RowComplete + value;
        divs = $(this).add($(this).next());

       if (RowComplete >= 12) 
       {
           divs.wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
           RowComplete = 0;
       }


    });
```

and its not giving desired result , its not adding first row .

```
<div class="row questionsRows">
<div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
  <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it:

```
var RowComplete = 0;
var divs;
$('.questionsRows').children('.coulmnQuestions').each(function () {

    var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    var getFirstClass = classes[0];
    var value = parseInt(getFirstClass.slice(7));

    if(RowComplete==0) {
        divs = $(this);   
    } else {
        divs = divs.add($(this))
    }

    RowComplete = RowComplete + value;

    console.log(RowComplete)       

   if (RowComplete >= 12) 
   {
       console.log(divs)
       divs.wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
       RowComplete = 0;
   }


});
```

Comment: The main problem was that `value` was not recognized like an integer. So you have to do `parseInt(value)`.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that this wont wrap the last row of items in a `<div class="wrapper"></div>` because of the `RowComplete >= 12` condition. You may want to add an or clause and also check if you are looking at the last child to wrap the final row of remainder divs.

Comment: Here's a JS Fiddle that works with Bootstrap 3 and handles the final row: http://jsfiddle.net/LE4hk/5/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in this line:

```
 divs = $(this).add($(this).next());
```

you are catching the next tag of `<div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>`, and you should get the same tag, I mean `<div class="col-md-4 coulmnQuestions"></div>` tag. So I'd do:

```
 divs = $(this).add($(this));
```

Anyway, if you add the code at http://jsfiddle.net it would be easier to see for us.